# Using BufferedReader to read a paragraph from a text file

Tags: java

I'm trying to give a user their daily horoscope. I have a large text file that looks somewhat like this:

> Aries
>
> There's just never a dull moment when you're around [continue horoscope] [continue horoscope] [continue horoscope] [continue horoscope] [continue horoscope] [continue horoscope] [continue horoscope] [continue horoscope] [continue horoscope] [continue horoscope] [continue horoscope] [end].
>
> Taurus
>
> Getting into the [continue horoscope] [continue horoscope] [continue horoscope] [continue horoscope] [continue horoscope] [continue horoscope] [continue horoscope] [continue horoscope] [continue horoscope] [continue horoscope] [continue horoscope] [continue horoscope] [continue horoscope] [continue horoscope] [continue horoscope] [end].

This text file contains all the horoscopes for all zodiac signs. I am trying to print out the correct paragraph based on the user's input. Can someone please help me with this? This is what I have so far:

```
public static void getDailyHoroscope() throws IOException{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please input your zodiac sign:");
    String sign = sc.nextLine();
    String file = ".txt file";

    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.print(line);
        }
        br.close( );
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Cannot find" + file);
}
```

I'm not sure how to proceed. This only spits out the entire text file in the console. I want to separate the output by paragraphs based on the user's sign.

Comment: One file contain all zodiac names ? aries, taurus....'

Comment: What have you actually tried? This is code to read and print a text file. What are your ideas on how to only print out the portion you want?

Comment: Fix your closing brace on the exception handler. Also, consider using try-with-resources thusly: `try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

TRY IT:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please input your zodiac sign:");
        String sign = sc.nextLine();
        String file = ".txt file";

        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String line;

            String sign2 = "";
            String content = "";
            String nl = System.getProperty("line.separator");
            //I assummed that your text not end with [end] for each sign zodiac.
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String l = line.trim().toLowerCase();
                //Check if line is equal than some zodiac sign.
                String sign3 = "";
                if (l.equals("aries")) {
                    sign3 = "aries";
                } else if (l.equals("tauro")) {
                    sign3 = "tauro";
                } //complete here all zodiac sing with else if.

                //Check if sign is equal than sign enter by user and data content for this sign still not ready. 
                if (sign2.length() == 0 && sign3.length() != 0 && sign.toLowerCase().equals(sign3)) {
                    sign2 = sign3;
                } else {
                    //Check if we need concatenate data for this sign.
                    if (sign2.length() > 0 && sign3.length() == 0) {
                        content += line + nl;
                    } else {
                        //If this line is equal other sign and content data we finalized and break.
                        if (sign2.length() > 0 && sign3.length() != 0) {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            br.close();

            System.out.println(content);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Cannot find" + file);
        }
```

Comment: Code-only answers are rarely so desirable. Consider adding an explanation as to why it should work for the OP.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you're doing a lot of work.

In your case it maybe a goods idea to read whole file first, split it by paragraphs, store it to some collection like `Map<Sign, Paragraph>` or `Set<Paragraph>` and then just search through that collection for an entry that is needed.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be continue reading the file, until you hit the users's input, followed by an empty line, and continue reading until you hit another new line followed by an empty line.

Something like this might work:

```
public static void getDailyHoroscope() throws IOException{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please input your zodiac sign:");
    String sign = sc.nextLine();
    String file = ".txt file";

    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line;
        boolean print = false;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            //If our print flag is false and we found a line that's just our users's sign
            if((!print) && line.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(sign)){
                //set our print flag to true
                print = true;
            }
            if(print){
                //if we're printing, and the line we just read was completley empty, unset our print flag.
                if(line.trim().isEmpty()){
                    print = false;
                }
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        }
        br.close( );
    }catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Cannot find" + file);
    }
}
```

Keep in mind i wrote this in notepad, might not work.

some considerations considering your above post:
In this code's current state, if it even works at all, it will probably print just the horoscope name, and then hit a blank line and stop printing, you will need to account for that possibility.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void getDailyHoroscope() throws IOException{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please input your zodiac sign:");
    String sign = sc.nextLine();
    String file = "C:/Users/Laptop/Downloads/horoscope.txt";
    sc.close();
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line;
        //include boolean exist sign, only because message
        boolean existSign = false;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.equalsIgnoreCase(sign)) {
                //skip first empty line
                br.readLine();
                line = br.readLine();
                while (line!=null && !(line.isEmpty())) {
                    System.out.println("\n"+line);
                    line = br.readLine();
                }

                existSign = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!existSign)
            System.out.println("Please input zodiac sign which exists");

        br.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Cannot find" + file);
    }
}
```

In outer while loop read line, while the line is not equal to sign.
Into if read one line to skip empty line, after thar read line with useful text. As long as it reaches the end or the next empty line, print that line and read next line. After inner while, set existSign on true and break outer while.

Comment: i can't imagine every single one of op's paragraphs literally end with `[end].`, just as i doubt they all have a content of `[continue horoscope]`

Comment: Please explain why this works. While code helps a lot, understanding usually needs more than just that.

Comment: Code-only answers are rarely so desirable. Consider adding an explanation as to why it should work for the OP.

Comment: Version 1.2 - Checking the empty string

Comment: Thanks for advice, this is my first answer.